# How to add html5 plugin in myeclipse 8.6 IDE?

Tags: html, myeclipse

Is it possible to add html5 in myeclipse?

myeclipse added html5 support from version 9.But I have only v8.6.

I think adding plugin is not like adding build path simply.

I dont want to download/upgrade myeclipse 9 or other versions.

pls reply frankly...Answers would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

If you "only have v8.6", I suggest you download and install a later release. It doesn't cost any more than you're paying now. If you need facilities in later releases, then get the later release.